# Feature 'a0f95442-e28c-41ff-afb0-c68341c014e7' for list template '108' is not installed in this farm

Tags: wiki, feature, error

After uninstalling Enhanced Wiki 2.0 Beta, whenever I go to `Site Actions -> Manage Content and Structure` I get the following error:

> Feature 'a0f95442-e28c-41ff-afb0-c68341c014e7' for list template '108'
>   is not installed in this farm.

Reinstalling the feature resolves the problem, but after uninstall I repeatedly get the same error. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @werwerwerwerwe: Could you please review the questions you've asked so far and click the tick next to any that have been the best answer for you? If you need more answers just edit your question with more detail and it will rise to the top of the list. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs if you still have a list instance based on the list template which is obviously uninstalled together with this Wiki you mentioned.

So deleting the list instance before removing the wiki solution should solve the problem.